# PowerShell - Add a Type switch parameter

Tags: azure, powershell

I have created a script that is able to locate users, groups, service principals, and applications on Azure. This is what I have.

```
$user = Get-AzADUser -ObjectId $objectID
if ($user)
{
    $user | Format-List Mail, DisplayName
}
else
{
    $group = Get-AzADGroup -ObjectId $objectID
    if ($group)
    {
        $group | Format-List DisplayName, Description, Id
    }
    else
    {
        $appO = Get-AzADApplication -ObjectId $objectID
        if ($appO)
        {
            Write-Host "ObjectID"
            $appO | Format-List ObjectType, DisplayName, Id, Type, ApplicationId
        }
        else
        {
            $appA = Get-AzADApplication -ApplicationId $objectID
            if ($appA)
            {
                Write-Host "Application ID"
                $appA | Format-List ObjectType, DisplayName, Id, Type, ApplicationId
            }
            else
            {
                $spO = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $objectID
                if ($spO)
                {
                    $spO | Format-List ObjectType, DisplayName, Id, Type, ApplicationId
                }
                else
                {
                    $spA = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $objectID
                    if ($spA)
                    {
                        $spA | Format-List ObjectType, DisplayName, Id, Type, ApplicationId
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Write-Warning "Object does not exist."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to write something that is able to call out the script using parameters. I want to be able to do something where the script is able to search all or be specific where to search. For example:

Search all:
./test.ps1 -ObjectId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx"

users and groups only:
./test.ps1 -ObjectId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx" -User -Group

applications only:
./test.ps1 -ObjectId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx" -App

I believe I will have to change my script overall. So far, this is what I have:

```
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidatePattern("^[a-z_0-9]{8}[-][a-z_0-9]{4}[-][a-z_0-9]{4}[-][a-z_0-9]{4}[-][a-z_0-9]{12}")]
        $objectID,
    
        [Parameter ()]
        [switch]$user,
        [switch]$group,
        [switch]$SP,
        [switch]$app
        )

    if ($user.IsPresent)
    {
        Get-AzADUser -ObjectId $objectID | Format-List Mail, DisplayName
    }
    if ($group.IsPresent)
    {
        Get-AzADGroup -ObjectId $objectID | Format-List DisplayName, Description, Id
    }
```

I'm stuck on how to go about Service Principal and Applications because both ObjectId and ApplicationId can be used to search.
Also, I'm unsure if this is the right way to tackle this. Since it seems that I will need to call out the parameters for this to work (I would like for the script to work even without calling out parameters). If anyone could help and confirm, it would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: It's generally _really bad form_ to explicitly call `Format-*` cmdlets from inside a function - it garbles the output object and makes it useless for further processing. Consider using `Select-Object` (if you want to trim the property set on the output objects), or just nothing at all - output the objects as-is

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will change it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm stuck on how to go about Service Principal and Applications because both ObjectId and ApplicationId can be used to search.

Use the same approach you used in the previous iteration of your function:

```
if($ServicePrincipal.IsPresent){
    $spO = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $objectID
    if ($spO)
    {
        $spO
    }
    else
    {
        $spA = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $objectID
        if ($spA)
        {
            $spA
        }
    }
}
```

---

> Also, I'm unsure if this is the right way to tackle this. Since it seems that I will need to call out the parameters for this to work (I would like for the script to work even without calling out parameters)

Define a default parameter set name for the function/script, then attach the switch parameters to a *different* parameter set name - this way you can easily determine whether to do *all* or just *some*:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='SearchAll')]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidatePattern("^[a-z_0-9]{8}[-][a-z_0-9]{4}[-][a-z_0-9]{4}[-][a-z_0-9]{4}[-][a-z_0-9]{12}")]
    $objectID,
    
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Switches')]
    [switch]$User,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Switches')]
    [switch]$Group,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Switches')]
    [switch]$ServicePrincipal,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Switches')]
    [switch]$App
)

if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Switches'){
  # at least one switch was passed, test for each switch, eg. if($App.IsPresent){ ... }
}
else{
  # no switches present, try one by one
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mathias! Another question: in my previous script, I have a write-warning at the end when no object is found. How can I add that to the new one?

Comment: That depends entirely on the behavior you're interested in :-) Should the user receive a warning only when not specifying a switch? Should the warning be there once for each switch that didn't result in any output?

Comment: A warning only when there is no result found!

Comment: Then all you need to keep track of is whether you ever get any hits - add a `$found = $true` statement every time you successfully get a hit on a search, then `if(-not $found){ Write-Warning}` at the very bottom :-)

Comment: Thank you! You've been so helpful! I hope you don't mind follow-up questions. I'm still new to PS, so how do I get the if and else statements started there? I did try it myself, but it seems I'm doing something wrong here : (